# Panel Won't Show When Called From MenuStrip

Tags: vb.net, panel, show, show-hide, menustrip

I have a `Panel` called `Panel_Manage_Calculations` on a `Form` called `Criteria`.  I have the visible property to a default of False.  When I call it from my `MenuStrip` called `MenutStrip_Main` with this code:

```
Private Sub ManageCalculationsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ManageCalculationsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Criteria.Panel_Manage_Calculations.Show()
End Sub
```

It does not show.  But if I put a button on `Criteria` and use this code:

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Panel_Manage_Calculations.Show()
End Sub
```

It will show.

The only other object on `Criteria` is a `DataGridView`.

How can I get `Panel_Manage_Calculations` to show when called from `MenutStrip_Main`?

**Additional Info**

The only other code that might run before I click is:

```
Private Sub AddToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem_Criteria.Click
    For Each mdiChild As Form In Me.MdiChildren
        If mdiChild.Name = "Criteria" Then
            mdiChild.Activate()
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
    Dim frmClientConfig As New Criteria
    frmClientConfig.MdiParent = Me
    frmClientConfig.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: if you set a break in the menu_Click, does it fire? Maybe the Handles clause has the wrong ref.  (It actually looks like it should be the other way around because button click has no handles clause, while the menu does.)

Comment: then it is not hooked up right....delete the sub and recreate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MenuItem Click might not be hooked up correctly for instance, the Handles... clause might refer to an older name or it might simply be **disabled**.  If the event is not firing, it is a menu thing.  Try creating a new menu entry for the code.

EDIT

If the event is not firing it is likely because a) the menu item is not enabled (PERHAPS) it gets disabled in code, b) it lacks a HANDLER which seems not to be the case or C) something ELSE has that handler attached or D) the wrong form is referenced

EDIT EDIT

Ok, so we have multiple MDI forms.  Based on the AddToolStripMenuItem, this is how it should look:

```
Private Sub ManageCalculationsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, _
        e As EventArgs) Handles ManageCalculationsToolStripMenuItem.Click

        frmClientConfig.Panel_Manage_Calculations.Show()
End Sub
```

Criteria is the form name (Class), the instance name is `frmClientConfig`.  You will need to rework how this form is handled:

```
    private frmClientConfig As Criteria      ' at the top of the MDI parent
```

In the menu Add click:

```
   frmClientConfig = New Criteria
   frmClientConfig.MdiParent = Me
   frmClientConfig.Show()
```

this is needed so that the menu click will know what a `frmClientConfig` is.  The problem was that you were issuing the `Show` to the class not the instance (which seems like it should throw an error).  BEWARE of where `NEW` is supposed to be used!

Comment: No the `Menu` is not on the same form as the `Button` and the `Panel`.

Comment: The edit did not work and they both fire.  I had had this same type of idea.

Comment: I got this error message `Additional information: Conversion from string "Criteria" to type 'Integer' is not valid.`